# How to Share on CRM2011 with XRM services?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I'm new to CRM 2011. How to Share (create share record contact between team) on CRM2011 with XRM services? I can't find on SDK and I don't know to where shared record on MSCRM db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `GrantAccessRequest` class. [Here's the SDK article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.grantaccessrequest.aspx)